# RDLC vs Crystal Reports vs Anything Else Free: I'm running Informix and using C# 4.0

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, informix, rdlc

I'm not sure which is the way to go for choosing a report type with my current setup. In the past I was using MS Server 2008 R2, MS SQL Server, MS.NET C# 3.5. Now I'm using something similar except my Database is IBM Informix and I'm using MS.NET C# 4.0.

I'd prefer to use RDLCs since I'm used to them, but I didn't wanna jump down that alley and debugging hell if they don't play well with Informix. In fact, I don't even wanna be limited to Crystal Reports vs RDLCs. I'm just curious what the best report type is to use my current setup. Oh, a **free** type if an alternative is suggested. Anyone else using Informix and reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advance warning: I don't have any experience of reporting from Informix.

Given that you are using C#, RDLCs would be the obvious route to take. Alternatively, if you are concerned about compatibility issues and your business can afford to spend on a commercial solution, then the IBM Cognos BI suite would definitely be worth a look.

On the free reporting solutions side, the three best-known open source reporting systems are probably BIRT, Jaspersoft and Pentaho - there is a comparison of them here: http://www.innoventsolutions.com/open-source-reporting-comparison.html

Comment: I went with RDLC files and just used a Collection<T> as the datasource and it worked great. I was used to creating RDL files and using a SQL Server datasource, but having a client-side file was just fine. I don't need dynamic report files, just dynamic data inside them.

Answer (score -1):

**[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/)**

- can read Crystal Reports templates
- powerful and simple API
- much more cost-efficient than Crystal Reports, and [costs less than open source](http://www.inetsoftware.de/support/news/why-i-net-crystal-clear-costs-less-than-open-source) solutions if you count in support costs (which you should).
- platform-independent because written in Java.
- can export to HTML or also a nice Java applet with zoom, search, and highlighting capabilities...
- if it has to be free, we also offer a completely free and fully functional [report designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer) - you'd only have to pay if you need a running server.

*full disclosure: I work for i-net software, so it's far to say this is a bit biased...but it is my opinion! :)*